# Find the modal value of a sample of numbers

Tags: c++, performance, reinventing-the-wheel

I am currently interested in implementing statistical measures. Other measures like mean, variance, and covariance are easy, but the mode feels harder than I thought. Is this good enough?

Note: `float` is used because I don't really intend to use it on big enough numbers. The size can be changed if needed.

Note 2: We cannot use vectors, any statistical related functions, and any other tool that can impact the performance of the code. What we can use though, are basic data types (`int`, `float`, `double`, `bool`, `char`, and the `long`, `short`, and `unsigned` versions) and simple conditional and looping structures. To add, the `auto` keyword is not allowed.

Probably unrelated, but still relevant: Why did I use "we" instead of "I" in the second note?
I'm still learning C++ in school, so I am limiting myself to what we can do in school even though it can really improve the performance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main () {
    int N, uniques = 0, j = 0;
    // N: number of elements; uniques: unique elements in list; j: list index
    cin >> N;

    float list[N], counters[N][2];
    // list[N]: the list of elements
    // counters[N][2]: the list of unique elements and the number of appearances
    bool found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> list[i];
        found = false;

        for (j = 0; j < uniques; j++) {
            if (counters[j][0] == list[i]) {
                counters[j][1]++;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            counters[uniques][0] = list[i];
            counters[uniques][1] = 1;
            uniques++;
        }
    }
    int max = counters[0][1], ind = 0, reps = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < uniques; k++) {
        if (max == counters[k][1]) {
            reps++;
        } else if (max < counters[k][1]) {
            ind = k, max = counters[k][1];
            reps = 1;
        }
    }

    if (reps == 1) {
        cout << "The mode of the data set is " << counters[ind][0] << " appearing " << max << " times";
    } else {
        cout << "undetermined " << reps;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

I added comments about the variable names.

Comment: By the way, I forgot to delete it, but the `cout << "undetermined" << reps;` is just a sanity check if it really counted correctly.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas to help you improve your code, and perhaps inspire you to learn more.

### Reconsider `using`

The code currently contains these two lines:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

That's not too terrible, but there are at least two ways to make it better.  First would be to put those *inside* `main` to limit any possible conflicts there instead of globally.  Better, in my view, would be to simply omit them and use `std::cin` and `std::cout` since they're only used in three lines in your entire program.  That way readers will instantly see that you're using the `std::` versions and not some other version.

### Decompose your program into functions

All of the logic here is in `main` in one dense chunk of code.  It would be better to decompose this into a separate function or functions.

### Avoid non-standard features

Others have mentioned this, but declaring an array with anything other than a compile-time number is not in standard C++ and so that should be avoided.  I *hope* your teacher isn't writing C++ code like this!

### Use modern C++ features

It is very likely you haven't learned about `std::ranges` or various other algorithms and data structures yet, but just to whet your appetite, here's a rewrite of your program using C++20 and all of the tools in the toolbox:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>

int main () {
    using myDataType = float;
    using myMapType = std::map<myDataType, unsigned>;
    myDataType value;
    myMapType counts;
    int N;
    for (std::cin >> N; N && std::cin >> value; --N) {
        ++counts[value];
    }
    auto mode = std::ranges::max_element(counts,{},&myMapType::value_type::second);

    std::cout << "The mode of the data set is " << mode->first 
              << " appearing " << mode->second << " times\n";
}
```

### Use a more efficient algorithm

It's good to learn how to write your own code, but given your restrictions, your options are somewhat limited.  Here's a suggestion for an alternative implementation that is somewhat more efficient, expressed in psuedo-code:

1. create "big enough" arrays for data and count
2. initialize overall item count and max element index to 0
3. for each read value:

   1. linearly search the data array for a matching value
   2. if it's new, add it to the array and set the count to 1 and increment the overall unique item count
   3. otherwise, it's not new so increment the count and compare to current max element index (updating the latter as appropriate)

At the end of this, the max element index will point to the index of the mode value and its associated count.

Comment: We haven't really dived in modern C++ features, since we use the "default" C++. Not sure what version it is, but maybe it's C++98.

Comment: Oh, I **really** hope it's at least C++11 or they are doing you a disservice by teaching you an obsolete language.

Comment: Also, I asked this from one of the answerers but no one responded yet: How bad is my method of grouping while getting the input? I can see how it's bad because it's nested loops, but I can't see the actual badness of it.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing all of your current restrictions.  One could easily make only a *single* pass through the data, extracting `value, count` pairs, and then make a single pass through the pairs to find the max count value.  If you can't use a `struct`, it's not going to be very pretty.

Comment: I've updated my answer to suggest an alternative algorithm.

Comment: In modern C++, I'd replace that loop with a range-based one `for (auto value: std::ranges::istream_view<float>{std::cin} | std::ranges::take_view{N})`.  The only downside (not relevant here) is that it will over-read by one element (incrementing its iterator before `take_view` calls a halt).

Answer (score 3):

Leaving alone the run-time sized arrays, lets look at complexity.

The nested loops are wasteful, both timewise, and spacewise. Consider to

1. read all numbers,
2. sort them, and
3. count (now adjacent) equals to find the mode

This will reduce the time complexity from \$O(n^2)\$ to \$O(n)\$, and the space complexity from \$O(n)\$ to \$O(1)\$ (the `counters` array is not needed anymore).

Also, if each phase is implemented as a function, the code will be much cleaner, readable and testable.

PS: Even if you are not allowed to use `std::sort`, nobody forbids you to *implement* an efficient sorting algorithm.

Comment: `std::sort()` is \$O(n \log n)\$. You can do it in \$O(n)\$ if you use radix sort of course. Space complexity is still \$O(n)\$ to store the sorted array.

Comment: @G.SliepenGood luck radix sorting `float`s.

Comment: The order of IEEE 754 floating point numbers is more or less preserved when bit-casting it to an integer of the same size, so it's perfectly doable.

Comment: @G.Sliepen This I what I am well aware of. Implementation please, better than `std::sort`.

Comment: Is it wasteful that I tried to group same elements in an array as the input is given?

Answer (score 2):

This is not standard C++:

> ```
>      int N;
>      ⋮
>      float list[N], counters[N][2];
> ```

Array dimensions are required to be compile-time constants.  Prefer to use a dynamically-sized container such as `std::vector`.

Given the crazy constraints you're working under (effectively using only the C-compatible subset of C++ - I'll even assume that smart pointers are forbidden), you'll have to write

```
float *list = new float[N];
```

Don't forget to `delete[]` the storage when it's no longer required.

Comment: I'm not sure if the array size changes, since it's only supposed to make an array of that size.

Comment: The size isn't fixed when you compile the code - because `N`'s value isn't known until run-time, you can't use `N` as an array dimension.  Creating the array using `new[]` is legal C++.

Comment: To be honest, not even `new[]` is allowed. Sorry if this is still unclear from the edit.

Comment: @soupless If you forbid dynamic allocation, I really hope you have a reasonable known upper limit so you can allocate statically.

Comment: I don't. I think you can just assume anything. Just say 1000, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the restrictions, the algorithm looks nice to me, but the code itself is a bit casual.
I post mine for you to compare the code structures.

```
void findMode()
{        
    const int maxSampleSize = 100000;
    int sampleSize;
    std::cin >> sampleSize;    
    if (sampleSize <= 0 || sampleSize > maxSampleSize) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid sample size";
        return;
    }

    static float uniqueValues[maxSampleSize];
    static int frequencies[maxSampleSize];
    int uniqueSize = 0;
    for (; sampleSize > 0; --sampleSize) {
        float value;
        std::cin >> value;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < uniqueSize && uniqueValues[i] != value)
            ++i;
        if (i == uniqueSize) {
            frequencies[uniqueSize] = 1;
            uniqueValues[uniqueSize] = value;
            ++uniqueSize;
        }
        else
            ++frequencies[i];
    }

    int modePos = 0;
    int modes = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < uniqueSize; ++i) {
        if (frequencies[i] == frequencies[modePos])
            ++modes;
        else if (frequencies[i] > frequencies[modePos]) {
            modePos = i;
            modes = 1;
        }
    }

    if (modes == 1) {
        std::cout << "The mode of the data set is " <<
            uniqueValues[modePos] << " appearing " <<
            frequencies[modePos] << " times";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "undetermined " << modes;
}
```

I use [static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable) array variables because array sizes are large.
Otherwise, we would eventually run into [troubles on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6262?view=msvc-170) if arrays would be allocated on stack.

Although, the example is not a model.
It is common for scientists, like in your case, to write a use-once code which doesn't require further maintanance.

---

We can observe that in the worst case (when all values are different) we perform about `N * N` "elementary" operations on the array elements.
To improve performance, we could sort arrays first (e.g., with [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort) in about `N * log(N)` operations in the worst case), and then find mode in a single run over sorted elements.
Here, I use insertion sort for simplicity.
It performs in about `N * N` operations.

```
void insertionSort(float arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int x = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        for (; j >= 0 && arr[j] > x; --j)
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        arr[j + 1] = x;
    }
}

void findMode()
{
    int sampleSize;
    std::cin >> sampleSize;

    const int maxSampleSize = 100000;
    if (sampleSize <= 0 || sampleSize > maxSampleSize) {
        std::cerr << "Invalid sample size";
        return;
    }

    static float sample[maxSampleSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; ++i)
        std::cin >> sample[i];
    
    insertionSort(sample, sampleSize);

    int modes = 0;
    int modePos = 0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 1, count = 1; i <= sampleSize; ++i) {
        if (i < sampleSize && sample[i - 1] == sample[i])
            ++count;
        else {
            if (count == maxCount)
                ++modes;
            else if (count > maxCount) {
                maxCount = count;
                modePos = i - 1;
                modes = 1;
            }
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    if (modes == 1) {
        std::cout << "The mode of the data set is " <<
            sample[modePos] << " appearing " <<
            maxCount << " times";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "undetermined " << modes;
}
```